# prove : The tangent to the curve ${x}^3+{y}^3=3axy$ at $(\frac{3a}{2},\frac{3a}{2})$ makes obtuse angle with the positive direction of $x$ axis?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, coordinate-systems

I have differentiated the equation from both side and put the value of coordinates given. Is there any better way? Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Implicit differentiation lets you calculate the slope of that tangent. What did you get?

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Doing so helps you to avoid negative attention to your posts! Feel free to view my first comment as a hint, and use it to generate some "context".

Comment: If you did what you wrote you should have found $y'=-1$ which means that the tangent forms an angle of $135°$ with $x$-axis

Comment: Yeah I tried and got the result as you mentioned as well. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Hint:

Point $(\frac {3a}2, \frac{3a}2)$ and also point (0, 0) i.e origin are exactly the points of intersection of line $y=x$ with curve $x^3+y^3=3axy$. if you plot the curve and line you  see that the tangent line at that point is perpendicular on line $y=x$, that is the gradient of tangent lines is $m=-1$ which means its angle with positive direction of x axis is obtuse.The equation of tangent line is:

$y-\frac 32=-1(x-\frac 32)$

Or: $y=-x +3$

Comment: Can you kindly attach some images? I having trouble to visualise it.  It will be better if you represent it in graphs

Comment: @S.MUKHERJEE, go to wolfram and write: plot x^3+y^3=3xy, y=x, y=-x+3. the last equation is for tangent line. here a=1, with any value of a the form of curve will be similar and line y=x is the symmetry axis of the curve.

Answer (score 1):

I trust that you tried. Only the last step did not connect somewhere.

Differentiate $ x^3+y^3-3 a x y =0$ implicitly and solve for the slope

$$ y'=y'(x)=\frac{ay-x^2}{y^2-ax}$$

The given point has

$$x=y$$

Plug in and the slope reduces to $-1$, so the the tangent makes CCW  $ 3 \pi/4$ obtuse angle to x-axis.

Comment: I not only tried but I also completed and got result as well but I was searching for something obvious, so searching google I got something called 'Descarte's follium' so I thought it may be related and asked some good method. Well, I also done it in the same way as you but using Newtonian notations expressions became very short and looking healthy. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I could guess something of what you said . However total silence of expression of effort on your part entails downvoting and closure. What to do,.. such is the homework traffic here. BTW, what is a Newtonian notation? Like $\frac{dy}{dx}?$

Comment: Yeah I can understand your point . I think that notation is from lebing. I was talking about your notations . Actually as I use it in android and also being naive mathjax took a lot of time, so I try to do with as little as possible.